# Make a Flutter textfield background as a notebook style (lined textfield)

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

I want to make a notebook page in my app like the one in the image below, I do not want a customPaint or SVG or any kind of photos I want when I scroll the page the lines still under the text, is there any custom textField with a lined background to use?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will have to wrap your own `TextField` with a `CustomPaint` widget. First, create a `TextPainter` with a `style` matching your `TextField` and call `layout` with a non-zero width.

```dart
final textPainter = TextPainter(
    text: TextSpan(
    text: ' ',
    style: style,
  ),
  textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
  textScaler: MediaQuery.textScalerOf(context),
)..layout(maxWidth: 12.0);
```

This `TextPainter` will give you access to the two values you need to draw lines at the correct offset.

```dart
/// The entire height of a line
textPainter.height

/// The distance from the top of a line to the bottom of a character on that line
textPainter.computeDistanceToActualBaseline(TextBaseline.alphabetic)
```

These can be combined to draw under every line of text:

```dart
class LinePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final double distanceToBaseline;
  final double lineHeight;

  /// If your `TextField` has any content-padding, 
  /// the top value will need to be added here
  final double offsetY;


  LinePainter({
    required this.distanceToBaseline,
    required this.lineHeight,
    this.offsetY = 0,
  });

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()..color = Colors.black;
    final intialOffset = offsetY + distanceToBaseline;
    for (double y = intialOffset; y < size.height; y = y + lineHeight) {
      canvas.drawLine(Offset(0, y), Offset(size.width, y), paint);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(LinePainter oldDelegate) {
    if (oldDelegate.distanceToBaseline != distanceToBaseline ||
        oldDelegate.lineHeight != lineHeight ||
        oldDelegate.offsetY != offsetY) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

All combined:

```dart
CustomPaint(
  painter: LinePainter(
    offsetY: 0, // Adjust this value with your `TextField` content-padding-top
    lineHeight: textPainter.height,
    distanceToBaseline: textPainter.computeDistanceToActualBaseline(TextBaseline.alphabetic),
  ),
  child: TextField(style: textStyle),
),
```

> Note: This example only works if your `Theme` is set to `useMaterial3: false`. I haven't yet figured out how to properly measure Material3 text.